# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and the main thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

Is it considered good practice to put calls to `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` in a queue to avoid blocking the main thread? Is this something that people do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was asking myself the same question and use to put this call in a background thread. It is really not needed. According to this [article](http://www.devsrealm.com/objective-c/playing-audio-in-your-ios-app/) the sound is already played in a background thread and  you don't know exactly when it will be played. I also verify this behavior in my own code.